# Using argmax to find largest number in a list of elements

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, argmax

Ok so I define 3 lists:

```
(define mylist '((pause 5 5 5)(note 3 4 5)(pause 3 4 4)))
(define myseqlist '(sequential-music-element (note 5 5 5) (note 4 3 4) (note 5 3 4)))
(define myparlist '(parallel-music-element (note 5 2 5) (note 4 2 4) (note 5 3 1)))
```

I have the predicates `note?` and `pause?` , essentially it checks if a list starts with `'note` or `'pause` then returns true or false.
However I can have list containing notes and pauses, which is callled a sequential-music-element (see `myseqlist` above) or parallel-music-element (see `myparlist` above)

How can I define a function that returns the degree of polyphony, that takes one of the 4 elements as a parameter? (see below for my attempt)

`pause` degree of polyphony = 0

`note` degree of polyphony = 1

sequence-music-element? **return the degree of the child with the largest degree**

parallel-music-element? **return the sum of the degrees of the children**

How do I complete this function:

```
(define (degree-of-polyphony elem)
  (cond [(note? elem) 1]
        [(pause? elem) 0]
        [(sequential-music-element? elem) (argmax ??? )]))
```

I am not sure how to make use of argmax in this case. It should check for the highest polyphony for the entire list of elements that `degree-of-polyphony` takes as a parameter.

Example: (degree-of-polyphony myseqlist) should return 1 since it has at least one note, if its all  pauses, it should return 0.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, it belongs to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license). If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395/584192)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just have to check if there's *at least* one `note` in the list, I'd go with this:

```
(define (note? ele)
  (and (pair? ele)
       (eq? (car ele) 'note)))

(define (degree-of-polyphony elem)
  (cond [(note? elem) 1]
        [(pause? elem) 0]
        [(sequential-music-element? elem)
         (if (ormap note? elem) 1 0)]))
```

`ormap` checks if there's at least one element that meets the given condition, `argmax` would be useful if we needed to find a maximum value.

Comment: it works if I give it myseqlist, but If it give it a list of only pauses, it does not return 0, it doesnt do anyhitng

Comment: Please show me the list. Maybe you passed a `parallel-music-element`? notice that you're not handling that case.

Comment: I passed `'((pause 5 5 5)(pause 3 4 5)(pause 3 4 4))`

Comment: Exactly, you didn't tag the list - it's not a note, a pause or  a sequential or a parallel list, so it doesn't fall under any of the conditions of your procedure, hence it returns void. You should pass it like this: `'(sequential-music-element (pause 5 5 5) (pause 3 4 5) (pause 3 4 4))`

Comment: but in this case I do not pass a sequence of elements. I pass a group of elements. So the degree of polyphony should return the maximum polyphony found (meaning if there is one note, it will return 1)

Comment: You have to define the input more precisely, then. Look your conditions: you check to see if it's a note, or a pause, or a sequence - none of those match a list like this: `'((pause 5 5 5) (pause 3 4 5) (pause 3 4 4))`. Either tag the input, or add an extra case in your procedure, to handle the new input type: a "group of elements"

Comment: Always a pleasure :)